# How can I close a single form instance in Access using VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

My application is designed to open several instances of the same form 'Request'. In the plot, by clicking in a specific button within the form a series of update actions may occur, followed by a close call of the current instance.

I've been able to manage the update operation for the current record. However, by calling

```
Docmd.Close
```

or

```
Docmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
```

the close event is triggered on the first opened instance of the form, and not necessarily the instance that triggered the operation.

Is there a way to close the specific instance by using VBA code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either identify the forms as you open these by their `hWnd` property, and/or add them to a *collection* where you identify them by a string of your choice.

The code could go like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private colForms As Collection
Private blnFrmsInit As Boolean

Function MyFormOpen(strFrmName As String, strInstanceName As String) 

    Dim frm As Form

    If blnFrmsInit = False Then
        Set colForms = New Collection
        blnFrmsInit = True
    End If
    Set frm = New Form_lfrmSpecialtyPreferences
    frm.Caption = strInstanceName
    colForms.Add frm, strInstanceName
End Function

Function MyFormClose(strInstanceName As String)
    colForms.Remove strInstanceName
End Function
```